# Multiple item in object

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

c# : EF Relation
.net core 
Good Afternoon 
I'm trying to create service for Dietician. 
I want to made Db that allow : 
One diet can have multiple Meal but 
one Meal can be at multiple diet 
now i has

```
public class DietList
    {
        public Guid DietListId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nazwa diety")]
        public string DietName { get; set; }

        public DateTime AddedDataTime { get; set; }
        public string Describe { get; set; }

        public List<Meal> MealId { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Meal
    {
        public Guid MealId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nazwa Posiłku")]
        public string MealName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Typ Posiłku")]
        public string MealType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Składniki")]
        public string Components { get; set; }

        public List<DietList>  DietListId { get; set; }
    }
```

but it throw exception : 
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'DietList.MealId' of type 'List'. 
Any solve of this problem ?

Comment: is the dotnet core or .Net Framework?

Comment: There is not enough info but I think you need to change the names of your navigation property.

Comment: it's a .net core im added information about that

Comment: Yes, change your names from MealId -> MealList and DietListId -> DietList. That may not be your issue, but it makes it clearer. Also, any fluent code?

Comment: Are you using DDD (Domain Driven Design) or Code-First Approach?

Comment: Code first approach.
@SteveGreene what you mean "fluent code" ?

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework Core, you cannot model Many-to-many relationships without an intermediate table. Read [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) for more information. You would have to create a model class to link your `DietList` and `Meal` instances.

Comment: Thx thats it! You are great. I'm sad that i can't + your comment

Comment: if vicnicius.ras posts it as an answer, you can set it as accepted answer Systu.

Comment: I'm cant because i had only 13 rep to +/- comment you need 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, you have a many-to-many relationship between `Diet` and `Meal`.
It needs an extra/middle table to store the linkage of entities, say `DietMeals`.
Then you can specify the relationship in the `DbContext` class.

You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many).

---

The property naming looks a little bit confusing. The collection name should in plural form, say:

```
Public List<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
```